# unexpected identifier daily reward function

Tags: javascript, html

Getting an unexpected identifier error in my function.

javascript

```
if (dailyRewardActive)                      //used to show how much time till it ends
{
    minutes = (((900000 - timer) / 60)/1000 - ((((900000 - timer)) % 60)/1000)
    seconds = ((900000 - timer) % 60000)   //getting it here

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes.toFixed(0)+":"+seconds.toFixed(0);
    timer = timer + 1000*timeBetweenTicks;
}
```

html

```
Time left on Daily Reward: <span id = "timer">0</span>
```

timer is a global variable (I know thats bad practice but would be very difficult to change in this code at this point)

Comment: Your `()` on the line above don't all add up...

Comment: Yes, I know you don't **have** to use semi-colons, but if you had, you would have gotten a slightly more intelligible error message, probably something like "Unexpected token `;`". Yet another reason to use semi-colons as sane people do.

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis on the line above are mismatched (not surprising, it's hard to look at!). If you space them out and match them up, you can find the missing one:

```
minutes = (
    (
        (900000 - timer) / 60
    ) /1000 - 
    (
        (
            ((900000 - timer)) % 60
        ) /1000
    )
//there's supposed to be another )
) //there we go
```